# How to Send Bulk Voice & SMS Broadcasting with Twilio

Tags: twilio, sms, voice

I'm a little new to programming and to Twilio

I'm trying to build a web app that can send bulk voice and SMS to a group of people by uploading an audio file and uploading an excel sheet with phone numbers and press send

can anyone help me get started?

Answer (score -3):

You can easily get started using the below resources.

[Deliver voice notifications over the phone in just three steps](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-notification-app)

[Twilio CodeExchange](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange)